# Finding if element is within a specified Array

Tags: c, pointers, byte, bit

I am trying to find if a ptr points to an element within the specified intArray. It is to return 1 if true and 0 if false.

Please see code.

```
int withinArray(int * intArray, int size, int * ptr) {

 int length = ptr - intArray;
 int signal = length >> 31;

  //size
  int size1 = (size - 1 - length) >> 31;


  return (signal | size1) + 1;

}
```

The program works. HOWEVER, I am not allowed to use the Binary integer operators: &, &&, |, ||, <, >, !=, /, % or Unary: ~ or Pointer operators: []. My solution so far required that I use the | symbol (see return statement). Is there anyway I can work around this? I have tried several other ways and all include the | or & symbol which are not allowed. I have been stuck on this for a while now and cannot think of a way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are not allowed to use the operators: &, &&, |, ||, <, >, !=, /, % or Unary: ~ or Pointer operators: [].

But can you use == operator? If yes, then the below solution will work for you.

```
int withinArray(int * intArray, int size, int * ptr) {
while(size--) {
    if(intArray == ptr) return 1;
    intArray++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's a solution that invokes no undefined behaviour, but isn't exactly fast on megabyte (let alone gigabyte) arrays.

Comment: Yes, this works! Didn't even think about doing this in a loop for some reason...Thank you so much!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "invokes no undefined behaviour" aside form the pesky `INT_MIN--`. ;-)

Comment: Hmm — @chux — it's getting late here, but I don't see `INT_MIN`, pesky or otherwise.  Would you elaborate?  There are risks with invalid parameters because the size is a signed `int` not `size_t`, but that only requires `-1` and not `INT_MIN` to throw things into disarray (or 'dat array).

Comment: @chux I have used the same method signature (as the post). As >,< operator wasn't allowed. So I tried to avoid that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Pathological `withinArray(intArray,INT_MIN, ptr)` makes for `int` overflow UB.    Yes any negative size leads to UB.  So not fully "solution that invokes no undefined behaviour"

Comment: @chux — OK; as I said, negative sizes cause trouble, but abuse of many C functions causes trouble.  I'd be tempted to `assert(size >= 0); if (size < 0) return 0;` (asserting when compiled without `-DNDEBUG` or equivalent; handling the error more or less safely when asserts are disabled).  Or thereabouts…

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If I add a check for INT_MIN or if the array is pointing to NULL. I will be making use of those operators which are not allowed.

Comment: The whole "operators not allowed" restrictions business is a stupid game that universities seem to delight in, but they are not realistic. No-one will tell you after graduation "you can't use operator _x_" without having an extremely good reason (e.g. bugs in the current version of the compiler). If the operator does the job correctly, use it. It also makes some of the finer points that @chux and I have been bandying around somewhat meaningless — real programs can use all operators. Nevertheless, comparing pointers for 'within range' using `<` etc is UB if the pointers are not within range.

Answer (score 2):

OP's Code relies on *undefined behavior* (UB).

Pointer subtraction `ptr - intArray` is UB if `ptr` is not in the array (or one pass the end).

Code could compare again each element one at a time.  Inefficient, but not UB.

Perhaps:

```
 // not allowed to use the Binary integer operators:&, &&, |, ||, <, >, !=, /, % or Unary: ~
int withinArray(int * intArray, int size, int * ptr) {
  while (size >= 1) {
    // Unclear if ==, ++ this counts for OP as a "Pointer operator"
    if (intArray == ptr) return 1;
    intArray++; 
    size--;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Code could attempt to convert the pointer to integers of sufficient range if available (pointers can readily exceed 32-bit `int` or even 64-bit) and then attempt an integer computation/compare.  Yet even that is not portable as 2 pointers that convert to 2 different integers may still point to the same address with non-linear address models.

Comment: You might mention `<stdint.h>` and `uintptr_t` (which is defined only if available).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True about `(u)intptr_t`, yet the integer subtraction/compare is not specified to map well to pointer subtraction/compare - so hurdles still remain..  I find this assignment of questionable practical value.

Comment: There's partly a problem of "the C standard says 'undefined behaviour', but actually it works fine on most machines that the OP is going to encounter".  It's really difficult. You're absolutely right that officially it is UB, because of weird systems (still in use?) like Intel 80286, or other segmented architectures. By the time we had Pentiums (and before that, I think), the segmented model existed for backwards compatibility but was almost entirely unused. I believe there are some IBM systems (iSeries, IIRC) where function pointers are 128 bits but data pointers are only 64-bits.  Messy!

Comment: And compiler writers jump in and make use of every undefined behaviour they can find, rather than making implementation definitions that would benefit programmers.  But never mind me; this is just sour grapes and I'm sure they're right to make life hell for people using their products.]

Comment: @chux This solution works, however I am not allowed to use the >= operator.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler FWIW I was [caught](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115165/29485) employing this same pointer subtraction UB as OP.  I have since found a work-around (un-posted) that did not use subtraction.

Comment: @overduekey  [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++) does not mean you code fails.  It means it is not reliable and will not necessary work with other compilers or other machines and so a weak program practice.

Comment: @overduekey If `>=` is not allowed, then add it and all others to your list of _not allowed_ operators, else we could endlessly find out new restrictions as answers are posted.